# Linux MAKEFILE access environment variable

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, makefile

I install OpenCV library in Linux. If I run command:

```
 echo $(pkg-config --libs opencv)
```

The result is as follow:
[image]

But if I run it from MAKEFILE like this:

```
all:
    @echo 1
    @echo $(pkg-config --libs opencv)
    @echo 2
```

Nothing is print out, what happend?
[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the terminal commands and output instead of using screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot `shell` in your shell commands: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html

Try this:

```
@echo $(shell pkg-config --libs opencv)
```

With it, you were printing the value of a variable named `pkg-config` (or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

`make` isn't the shell, and the syntax is different. You probably want to have the Makefile echo the result of running `pkg-config` in a shell, thus:

```
all:
    @echo 1
    @echo $(shell pkg-config --libs opencv)
    @echo 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and correct way to do this is

```
all:
    @echo $$(pkg-config --libs opencv)
```

Using `shell` makefile function is unnecessary and does not actually correct what is wrong with the OP code.